# Shifting position

Tags: titlesec, book-design

I used this to type a book(This is not the entire command).But I want the page to begin from the top leftmost corner.Is there a way to do it?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{\mbox{SEQUENCES AND SERIES}}
{\large{Now that the foundations of the real number system $\mathbb{R}$ have been added}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the output I got.Is there a way to shift it to the top leftmost corner or something like that?]

I thoughy maybe instead of this,I could try using pstricks and assign it positions.But is there any better way to do it?

Comment: note that `\large` does not take an argument so should be `\large Now...` not `\large{Now...`  But if you want the body text to be 12pt it is better to use `\documentclass[12pt]{report}` rather than using `\large` in the body of the document.

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean by top left here. The Chapter 3 heading is already flush left, you are loading the titlesec package which provides commands to specify the space around headings, so you can reduce the vertical space before the heading if that is what you need.

Comment: @David Carlisle I meant I want my chapter name and paragraphs to start from the left corner.How can I reduce the vertical space before heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the package `titlesec`, already loaded, and  use `\titlespacing` to set the spaces around the chapter title. Before must configure `\chapter` using `\titleformat`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec,amssymb}

\usepackage{showframe} % only to show margins

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}
{-20pt}% space before
{35pt}% space after


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{2}

\chapter{\mbox{SEQUENCES AND SERIES}}

{\large Now that the foundations of the real number system $\mathbb{R}$ have been added}
\end{document}
```